# find the domain of convergence of the given series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ n.4^n }{3^n}x^n(1-x)^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

find the domain of  convergence  of the given  series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ n.4^n }{3^n}x^n(1-x)^n$$

My attempt :     $\frac{ n.4^n }{3^n}x^n(1-x)^n = n.(\frac{4}{3}x - \frac{4}{3}x^2)^n$
now $$-1 <|n.(\frac{4}{3}x - \frac{4}{3}x^2)^n| < 1$$

=  $-1< n\frac{4}{3}(x- x^2)< 1$

=$-\frac{3}{4}< n(x- x^2)< \frac{3}{4}$

Now  im not able  to proceed  Further  pliz help  me

thanks u

Comment: What did the "${}^n$" in the exponent do to you that its friend "$n\cdot$" did not? Because you made one disappear while leaving the other one there.

Comment: Sorry but why are you even interested in the condition $$-1 <|n(\tfrac43x - \tfrac43x^2)^n| < 1$$ in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left\lvert\frac{n4^n}{3^n}x^n(1-x)^n\right\rvert}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]n\frac43\bigl\lvert x(1-x)\bigr\rvert=\frac43\bigl\lvert x(1-x)\bigr\rvert.$$Therefore, by the root test, the series converges if $\bigl\lvert x(1-x)\bigr\rvert<\frac34$ and diverges if $\bigl\lvert x(1-x)\bigr\rvert>\frac34$. Actually, it also diverges when $\bigl\lvert x(1-x)\bigr\rvert=\frac34$, because then we dont't have$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert\frac{n4^n}{3^n}x^n(1-x)^n\right\rvert=0.$$So, the series converges if and only if $\bigl\lvert x(1-x)\bigr\rvert<\frac34$.

Comment: sir  can u  more elaborate

Comment: @stupid It's done.

Comment: To complete your good work, I made a plot of the region containing $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\,\frac{4^n\,n}{3^n}\,z^n\,(1-z)^n$$ converges (and it converges to $\dfrac{12z(1-z)}{(3-4z+4z^2)^2}$).  This region is the interior of the oval seen in this [WolframAlpha plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B%7B1%2F2*Sqrt%5BSqrt%5B16x%5E2-16x%2B13%5D-(4x%5E2-4x%2B2)%5D,-1%2F2*Sqrt%5BSqrt%5B16x%5E2-16x%2B13%5D-(4x%5E2-4x%2B2)%5D%7D,%7Bx,-1%2F2,3%2F2%7D%5D).

Answer (score 1):

At the end you made a mistake in using the ratio test.  It should be $|\frac{n}{n-1}(x-x^2)|\lt  \frac{3}{4}$. Since $\frac{n}{n-1}\to 1$, you need to test $|x-x^2|\lt \frac{3}{4}$.   The solution is $-\frac{1}{2}\lt x \lt \frac{3}{2}$.